# Dataset import using logstash to ElasticSearch is slow

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I need to import text file (no structure, just line by line data) but it seems to me it could do better. I already made some changes to logstash configuration and gained about 200% using -b and -w option (I found sweet spot). But still it is too slow for my needs.

> HW: i5 7600k @ 4.5GHz, 32GB DDR4 ram, SSD intel 512GB File: 26GB, ~800
>   000 000 lines Current speed with -b 1000 and -w 16 options: 2 500 000
>   per min, ~41 000

per s

The speed I am looking for is around 500 000 per s.

Logstash configuration file:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/w-nsa/dataset.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }

}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://8.8.3.2:9200"
        index => "test"
    }
}
```

Comment: run it on several logstash instances

Comment: @Mysterion I don't think it's a good idea: it would mean duplicating the JVM overhead, especially since the -w option allows to parallelize the process.

Comment: @baudsp how you will make it faster? :)

Comment: @Mysterion I don't think I could, unless by adding more machines to split the job between them. But leandrojmp's comment on elasticsearch perf is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bottleneck could be the indexing speed on the elasticsearch side.

How are your servers configured? Logstash and Elasticsearch are on the same machine? What is the Java Heap for each one?

This [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html) from elastic has a few tips to improve indexing speed.

You should try to index your data and monitor the IO on the elasticsearch machine using a tool like `iostat` and `iotop` to see how the machine behaves under the heavy load.

Comment: Heap is 12 GB for elastic, on LogStash is default value which I can't remember now, yes they are on the same machine but on different SSD disk. Disk seems to be not utilized 100% but like 40%, When using grep on file I get up to 512MB/s .

Comment: The Logstash default heap size is 1GB, since you increased the batch size from the default 125 to 1000, maybe you could try to increase the Logstash heap size, test it with 2GB or 4GB, so you will still have 50% of your memory for other process.

Have you checked the IO performance of the elasticsearch disk while indexing with `iostat`?